# Can I use one time use puppy pads for toddler potty training while they sleep at night?

Tags: toddler, sleep, potty-training, sleep-training

I'm starting to potty train my child at 20 months by not sleeping with a diaper on. It gets tiring to change / wash the bed sheets every night. I was thinking of using disposable one time use puppy training pads. Is this a feasible use case for something that is meant for animals? I means its just a super absorbent pad or is there another suggestion to create a quick environment to change the sheets when they wet themselves during sleep?

Comment: I won't speak for all "puppy pad" products, but the ones we have for our puppy are designed to have some kind of scent in it so that the dog will use it.  I don't know what that entails, but I would say I would want to find some kind of rash on my kid from using one overnight.  I would shop drug or medical supply store for pads that are made for that kind of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Don't. Maybe they will work and maybe they won't but those items are designed for animals, not children.

Animals don't wear clothing while your child *should* be wearing clothing at night time. Wet clothing while laying in a wet puppy trainer is not going to go great in the way of hygiene.

If you are tired changing sheets, having to air out mattresses or futons, maybe your child is not ready for sleeping without a diaper at night time. 20 months is ***extremely*** fast for attempting this and I'd almost say it's counter-productive.

I see you are in Tokyo, so if wearing something that feels like underwear and less like a diaper is your goal, go to AEON or any local department store and buy an appropriate size package of メリーズパンツタイプ (pants-type diapers). A pack will set you back ~1700円. Only let them wear it at night time and let your child assist with putting them on. They worked wonders for both of my children who have already gone through potty-training.

Do not use a puppy trainer pad for your child. It's the same level of waste as a diaper.

Comment: i just found that they sell these pads for adults too. They are used in hospitals for elderly.

Comment: Why in the world would you say that it is demeaning?  The child will not be offended, and the parents are not intending to insult the child.  If no-one feels either demeaned or demeaning, then **it isn't**.

Comment: @BenI. I have removed that line. I will however say that although this may be a cultural/personal mindset thing, I feel it is demeaning and I would never expect my children to sleep on a trainer pad made for animals when a diaper would work just well and is specifically designed for a human children.

Comment: @SomeShinyObject Fair enough. In that case, the same product is also available for babies. They're sold as animal pads, adult pads, and changing table pads. As far as I can tell, these all may well have come off of the same factory line. The only difference that I know of is the lettering on the side of the package.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why it wouldn't help. It would produce a lot of waste though and I believe they are thin and tend to bunch up and sound "crinkly", so perhaps look into what washable fabric options there are. I think looking up "hospital pad" or something similar may be a useful search term.

I use a fabric pad (it was originally a "hospital pad" my parents had leftover from when my sister and I were kids) for my dog to give her a place where she is allowed to go without getting in trouble while we are at work - it is sturdy enough that it does not bunch up and it washes super easily. This I think would work better than the disposable "puppy pads". (The puppy pads are usually sold with a "frame" to keep them from bunching up). I think they would be too easy to move out of the way when tossing and turning while sleeping to offer much protection.

Another thing to consider though: the quilt/top sheet. A pad may protect the bottom sheet, but the top sheet can still be soiled. (I have no answer for this problem unfortunately.